# Returning a Mock from a package function

Tags: go, testify

I'm fairly new to Go and I'm having some issues with writing tests, specifically mocking the response of a package function.

I'm writing an wrapper lib for `github.com/go-redis/redis`. At the moment it only really has better errors for failures, but it will be expanded with statsd tracking further down the line, but I digress...

I have the following go package that I have created

```
package myredis

import (
    "time"

    "github.com/go-redis/redis"
    errors "github.com/pkg/errors"
)

var newRedisClient = redis.NewClient

// Options - My Redis Connection Options
type Options struct {
    *redis.Options
    DefaultLifetime time.Duration
}

// MyRedis - My Redis Type
type MyRedis struct {
    options Options
    client  *redis.Client
}

// Connect - Connects to the Redis Server. Returns an error on failure
func (r *MyRedis) Connect() error {

    r.client = newRedisClient(&redis.Options{
        Addr:     r.options.Addr,
        Password: r.options.Password,
        DB:       r.options.DB,
    })

    _, err := r.client.Ping().Result()
    if err != nil {
        return errors.Wrap(err, "myredis")
    }

    return nil
}
```

My problem is that I want `redis.NewClient` to return a mock. This is the test code that I wrote, but it's not working:

```
package myredis

import (
    "testing"

    "github.com/go-redis/redis"
    "github.com/stretchr/testify/assert"
    "github.com/stretchr/testify/mock"
)

type redisStatusCmdMock struct {
    mock.Mock
}

func (m *redisStatusCmdMock) Result() (string, error) {
    args := m.Called()
    return args.Get(0).(string), args.Error(1)
}

type redisClientMock struct {
    mock.Mock
}

func (m *redisClientMock) Ping() redis.StatusCmd {
    args := m.Called()
    return args.Get(0).(redis.StatusCmd)
}

func TestConnect(t *testing.T) {
    assert := assert.New(t)

    old := newRedisClient
    defer func() { newRedisClient = old }()

    newRedisClient = func(options *redis.Options) *redis.Client {
        assert.Equal("127.0.0.1:1001", options.Addr)
        assert.Equal("password", options.Password)
        assert.Equal(1, options.DB)

        statusCmdMock := new(redisStatusCmdMock)
        statusCmdMock.On("Result").Return("success", nil)

        clientMock := new(redisClientMock)
        clientMock.On("Ping").Return(statusCmdMock)

        return clientMock
    }

    options := Options{}
    options.Addr = "127.0.0.1:1001"
    options.Password = "password"
    options.DB = 1

    r := MyRedis{options: options}

    result, err := r.Connect()

    assert.Equal("success", result)
    assert.Equal(nil, err)
}
```

I get the following error: `cannot use clientMock (type *redisClientMock) as type *redis.Client in return argument`. I think I read that I need to mock all the functions of `redis.Client` in order to be able to use it as a mock in this case, but is that really the case? That seems like it's overkill and I should be able to do this in some way. How do I go about getting this test to work, or do I need to restructure my code so that it's easier to write the test?

Comment: `redis.Client` is a *struct* type and in Go struct types are simply *not* mockable. However interfaces in Go *are* mockable, so what you can do is to define your own newredisclient func that instead of returning a struct returns an interface. And since interfaces in Go are satisfied *implicitly* you can define your interface such that it `redis.Client` will implement it.

Comment: Any chance you could provide a link on how I would go about doing that?

Comment: Something like this: https://play.golang.com/p/a567Q6NpSU8

Comment: @mkopriva I think that deserves to be an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`redis.Client` is a *struct* type and in Go struct types are simply *not* mockable. However interfaces in Go *are* mockable, so what you can do is to define your own "newredisclient" func that instead of returning a struct returns an interface. And since interfaces in Go are satisfied implicitly you can define your interface such that it will be implemented by redis.Client out of the box.

```
type RedisClient interface {
    Ping() redis.StatusCmd
    // include any other methods that you need to use from redis
}

func NewRedisCliennt(options *redis.Options) RedisClient {
    return redis.NewClient(options)
}

var newRedisClient = NewRedisClient
```

---

If you also want to mock the return value from `Ping()`, you need to do a bit more work.

```
// First define an interface that will replace the concrete redis.StatusCmd.
type RedisStatusCmd interface {
    Result() (string, error)
    // include any other methods that you need to use from redis.StatusCmd
}

// Have the client interface return the new RedisStatusCmd interface
// instead of the concrete redis.StatusCmd type.
type RedisClient interface {
    Ping() RedisStatusCmd
    // include any other methods that you need to use from redis.Client
}
```

Now `*redis.Client` does *not* satisfy the `RedisClient` interface anymore because the return type of `Ping()` is different. Note that it doesn't matter that the result type of `redis.Client.Ping()` satisfies the interface type returned by `RedisClient.Ping()`, what matters is that the method signatures are different and therefore their types are different.

To fix this you can define a thin wrapper that uses `*redis.Client` directly and also satisfies the new `RedisClient` interface.

```
type redisclient struct {
    rc *redis.Client
}

func (c *redisclient) Ping() RedisStatusCmd {
    return c.rc.Ping()
}

func NewRedisCliennt(options *redis.Options) RedisClient {
    // here wrap the *redis.Client into *redisclient
    return &redisclient{redis.NewClient(options)}
}

var newRedisClient = NewRedisClient
```

Comment: Thanks for this. This has been quite the learning experience, it's really strange to me that I can have a `struct` in a package inherit a `interface` that I've declared.