# How do I improve the testability of go library methods

Tags: go, mocking

I'm writing some code that uses a library called [Vault](https://github.com/hashicorp/vault). In this library we have a `Client`. My code makes use of this `Client` but I want to be able to easily test the code that uses it. I use only a couple methods from the library so I ended up creating an interface:

```golang
type VaultClient interface {
    Logical() *api.Logical
    SetToken(v string)
    NewLifetimeWatcher(i *api.LifetimeWatcherInput) (*api.LifetimeWatcher, error)
}
```

Now if my code is pointed at this `interface` everything is easily testable.. Except let's look at the `Logical()` method. It returns a `struct` [here](https://github.com/hashicorp/vault/blob/62d0ecff3d155c75f932075da47fea003fa7a772/api/logical.go#L41). My issue is that this `Logical` struct also has methods on it that allow you to `Read`, `Write`, ex:

```golang
func (c *Logical) Read(path string) (*Secret, error) {
    return c.ReadWithData(path, nil)
}
```

and these are being used in my project as well to do something like:

```golang
{{ VaultClient defined above }}.Logical().Write("something", something)
```

Here is the issue. The `Logical` returned from the call to `.Logical()` has a `.Write` and `.Read` method that I can't reach to mock. I don't want all the logic within those methods to run in my tests.

Ideally I'd like to be able to do something similar to what I did above and create an `interface` for `Logical` as well. I'm relatively new to Golang, but I'm struggling with the best approach here. From what I can tell that's not possible. Embedding doesn't work like inheritance so it seems like I *have* to return a `Logical`. That leaves my code unable to be tested as simply as I would like because all the logic within a `Logical`'s methods can't be mocked.

I'm sort of at a loss here. I have scoured Google for an answer to this but nobody ever talks about this scenario. They only go as far as I went with the initial `interface` for the client.

Is this a common scenario? Other libraries I've used don't return `struct`s like `Logical`. Instead they typically just return a bland `struct` that holds data and has no methods.

Comment: Another way of testing is to configure the struct for testing (in this case the [`Client`](https://github.com/hashicorp/vault/blob/62d0ecff3d155c75f932075da47fea003fa7a772/api/client.go#L397)). I haven't tried but I think you can pass `*http.Client` in the NewClient.

This way you can setup a test server with `srv := httptest.NewServer` and define the vault server behavior by yourself, then pass the `srv.Client()` to vault NewClient config for testing.

Comment: I'm hoping to avoid testing things with an `httptest.NewServer` if at all possible. It feels more tedious that should be necessary for something like this. I'm totally open to the idea if there's no alternatives though! :)

Comment: @user2767260 You can change your original interface to return another interface, i.e. change `Logical() *api.Logical` to `Logical() ApiLogical` where `ApiLogical` is an interface declared by you and whose methods match those of `*api.Logical`, then you would use thin wrappers to satisfy the new `VaultClient` interface. As an example see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58022874/965900

Comment: @mkopriva Thank you! That is exactly what I was looking for. If you want to add an answer down below I'd be happy to accept it! :D

Answer (score 0):

```
package usecasevaultclient

// usecase.go
type VaultClient interface {
    Logical() *api.Logical
    SetToken(v string)
    NewLifetimeWatcher(i *api.LifetimeWatcherInput) (*api.LifetimeWatcher, error)
}

type vaultClient struct {
   repo RepoVaultClient
}

// create new injection
func NewVaultClient(repo RepoVaultClient) VaultClient {
  return &vaultClient{repo}
}

func(u *vaultClient) Logical() *api.Logical {
 // do your logic and call the repo of
   u.repo.ReadData()
   u.repo.WriteData()
}
func(u *vaultClient) SetToken(v string) {}
func(u *vaultClient) NewLifetimeWatcher(i *api.LifetimeWatcherInput) (*api.LifetimeWatcher, error)

// interfaces.go
type RepoVaultClient interface {
   ReadData() error
   WriteData() error
}

// repo_vaultclient_mock.go
import "github.com/stretchr/testify/mock"

type MockRepoVaultClient struct {
   mock.Mock
}

func (m *MockRepoVaultClient) ReadData() error {
      args := m.Called()
      return args.Error(0)
}

func (m *MockRepoVaultClient) WriteData() error {
      args := m.Called()
      return args.Error(0)
}


// vaultClient_test.go

func TestLogicalShouldBeSuccess(t *testing.T) {
  mockRepoVaultClient = &MockRepoVaultClient{}

  useCase := NewVaultClient(mockRepoVaultClient)

  mockRepoVaultClient.On("ReadData").Return(nil)
  mockRepoVaultClient.On("WriteData").Return(nil)

  // your logics gonna make this response as actual what u implemented
  response := useCase.Logical()

  assert.Equal(t, expected, response)
}
```

if you want to  test the interface of Logical you need to mock the ReadData and WriteData , with testify/mock so u can defined the respond of return of those methods and you can compare it after you called the new injection of your interface

Comment: Hey Pocket, I updated my initial question a little bit to add more explanation. It's not so much that I need to perform logic within the `Logical` method, but instead I need to be able to test the methods that exist for a `Logical`. I added an example of my usage in the question above. `VaultClient.Logical().Write("something", something)` is my usage. The `VaultClient` is an interface so that's easy to test, but the `.Write` can't be mocked because it seems I _have_ to return an actual `Logical` from the `VaultClient` nonetheless. This seems to heavily conflict with my ability to test.

Comment: i think u should create the interface Repo what i wrote above, so in the method ReadData you should call the vault Read from logical, because what i know that you want test the interface you pass there,